# Hibernate 6 Query validation fails

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following query in my code which used to work with Hibernate 5.6 but now fails to validate with Hibernate 6.2 (migration to Spring boot 3.1).

The error is the following:

```
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method
(...)
and re.niveauResponsabilite.code =1]; this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser [select a from ResponsableEleve re
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't compare test expression of type [BasicSqmPathSource(code : String)] with element of type [basicType@1(java.lang.Integer,4)]
(...)
```

Current query and mapping are:

```java
@Query("""
        select a from ResponsableEleve re
        where re.id = :personneId and
        re.niveauResponsabilite.code = 1""")
Adresse findAdresse(@Param("personneId") Integer personneId);
```

```java
@Column(name = "NIVEAU_RESPONSABILITE", nullable = false, length = 1,
        columnDefinition = "char(1)")
private String code;
```

I am not sure if it's the mapping that should be modified (I tried `@JdbcType(CharJdbcType.class)` whitout luck) or if I should modify the Query ? Or Both ?

### Update from Arnaud comment:

Just adding `'1'` solves the problem so that's perfect. Just wondering why this started to fail with Hibernate 6.2.

Comment: ... are you sure that query used to work ? I don't see how it could without an "and" or "or" between "where re.id = :personneId" and "re.niveauResponsabilite.code = 1" (I'm used to nativeQuery = true when using @Query, but still). The error seems to say exactly that : parser error.

Comment: As the error states, you are attempting to compare a `String` type with an `int` . Try putting `'1'` in your query , not just `1`.

Comment: I'm sure it's working with the older version of Hibernate, and yes using just ```'1'``` does resolve it, thanks ! By the way, yes the and is missing here, as I cut the query for brevity, sorry for that :)